# Partial Content Get Request

Tags: python, http, sockets, get

I'm trying to get partial content from the website [http://dijkstra.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~cs421/partialt11.txt](http://dijkstra.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Ecs421/partialt11.txt)

Below is my get request:

```
cmd2 = "GET /{} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {}\r\nAuthorization: Basic {}\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes=1-1800\r\n\r\n".format(path2, host2, token2)
```

where host2, path2, token2 are defined 100% correctly. matchlist[][] gives the range of bytes I want to recover.
However, no matter what I write into Accept-Ranges: bytes=...-..., I get the same "amount" of the file. It is not the whole file. Plus I get the 200 OK message instead of Partial Content as the status code. Even accept-ranges header is not filled in the response. Why is that? Thanks in advance. Below is the response:

```
'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2022 08:29:23 GMT\r\n
Server: Apache/2.4.6 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.40 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.16.3\r\n
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Mar 2022 10:38:52 GMT\r\n
ETag: "73a-5d99e786e8eae"\r\n
Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n
Content-Length: 1850\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n
Modem Noise Killer (alpha version)\n\nWith this circuit diagram, some basic tools including a soldering iron, and\nfour or five components from Radio Shack, you should be able to cut the\nnoise/garbage that appear'
```

Answer (score 2):

Accept-Ranges is a server response indicating that it will accept partial requests. Client should send Range - i.e., in your case:

```
Range: bytes=1-1800
```

However, it's worth noting that the server *MAY* ignore Range

Comment: Thank you so so much <3 Its still doing the same thing so I guess the server is ignoring Range. I guess I'll downl9ad all end then take out the desired parts.